# Vim is pasting in strange manner

Tags: vim

```
foo()
{
...
}

bar()
{
...
}

baz()
{
...
}
```

For example I want to paste foo(), between bar() and baz(). I do <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>, and I expect something like this (or at least something near to this behavior):

```
foo()
{
...
}

bar()
{
...
}

foo()
{
...
}
baz()
{
...
}
```

But vim just collides what I'm trying to paste with text under cursor, like this:

```
foo()
{
...
}

bar()
{
...
}
foo() 
{     baz()
...   {
}     ...
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `<C-v>` Instead use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

Better way might be to use text objects like <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to yank whole block (paragraph) and paste

Comment: Can't see any difference between Shift-v and C-v, but yanking whole block with "y a p" helped, thanks for useful combination.

Comment: C-v is block selection, S-v is line selection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `P` uppercase to paste before the cursor.

Also check out [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com) for Vim related questions.